# Bug in Firefox with plugin Video DownloadHelper

Tags: discussion, support, bug, chat, firefox

I like to be present in more chat's rooms about SO but not always present.
From yesterday when I install the plugin Video DownloadHelper and the chat's room have a bad view.

Image's home:
[image]

Then go and analyze the html page:
[image]

**Html**:

```
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1633143275" style="width:280px;height:210px;top:1197px;left:141px"></div>
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1633134470" style="width:300px;height:232px;top:1477px;left:141px"></div>
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1633134470" style="width:300px;height:150px;top:3930px;left:141px"></div>
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1133464472" style="width:347px;height:29px;top:455px;left:1008px"></div>
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1133464472" style="width:143px;height:15px;top:533px;left:1000px"></div>
<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1133470176" style="width:0px;height:0px;top:0px;left:0px"></div>
```

Trying for delete all tags `<div class="vdh-mask vdh-1133464472"` I have a normal view.

Result:
[image]

So I create this question and I want to inform the administrators that is possible for solve this bizarre bug with add rules css [LINK](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/video-downloadhelper-q-and-a/gxE1AOoivww/ewwt15Gsyz8J):

```
.vdh-mask {
display: none;
}
```

Already try on my laptop and work... idk if it cause other conflicts in other page:
[image]

Comment: So do you expect SE to modify their CSS? If the problem is caused by a third party plugin, then it must be solved by its developers.

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani: you can't expect SE to make adjustments for each and every one of the thousands of mis-coded plugins out there. File a bug on that plugin's support site. (Oh, and stay polite please.)

Comment: ok just send a report to developers's plugin.
I hope that will solved this bug plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a bug in DownloadHelper 5.3.0. Version 5.3.1 has been reported to fix the issue. This last version is under review at Mozilla but can be installed from now from https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/versions/?page=1#version-5.3.1